# Generating random unique double values in Java

Tags: java, math, random, double, unique

I need a collection of 64-bit floating point random numbers, and they should be distinct. Is there a library routine for this, or should I manually search for duplicates?

It is actually more important to have the numbers not being closer than some very small constant \epsilon. Is there a library routine for that as well?

Comment: You cannot avoid searching for duplicates.  You can, however, delegate it to a library routine.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if you know the period of a Linear Congruential Generator is larger than your required number of samples, you do not need to search for duplicates.

Comment: Apparently OP did not know this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use `streams` for that.

```
double[] array = new Random().doubles()
                             .distinct()
                             .limit(500) // How many you want.
                             .toArray();
```

Comment: Another nice use of JDK 8.  I'm trying to practice more and more with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` collection. It won't allow insertion of unique values. Below is an example:

```
Set<Double> doubles = new HashSet<Double>();
Random r = new Random();
for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++){
    doubles.add(r.nextDouble() * 100);
}
```

Comment: Note that you still need to convert your Doubles to doubles ;)

Comment: Java will take care of it.

Comment: You should use `doubles.size() < 100`, otherwise you'll end up with fewer than 100. (Or whatever the number of distinct numbers you want is).

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to understand, how a random-number-generator works. A sequence of positive integers, long integers, with no doubles in it, is calculated. This sequence is at least 2^31 elements long. The real doubles in the range of 0.0 ..... 1.0 are the result of a floating point division.Floating point division is never exact. 
If you use this real numbers to generate integer in smaller interval, it is the quickest method,to use a random-number-generator, which gives you positive integer from that interval.
The algorithm for the Lehmer-generator is
x1 = (x0 * m) % div
x0 : the last random number,x1 the next random number. Div and m are prime numbers. m < div. The first x0 is select by the user.called seed number.
It is clear, that the x_i are smaller then div. For the other properties of good random-number-generator, there is no short proof.

My suggestion:
Write a method for a Lehmer-generator with m = 279470273 and div = 4294967291. I found these numbers on several web pages. Div = 2^32-5, so you can be sure to get a sequence of nearly 2^32 positive long integer,all different. Convert them to doubles and divide them with div as double. You get doubles in the open interval (0.0, ..... 1.0) and all these doubles are different. 
The random integers are small enough, that the quotients are also different. If you use a random generator, which generate bigger integer random numbers, you can not sure, that doubles are also different, the reason are rounding errors.

Comment: The name of D. H. Lehmer was misspelled (Lehmert).

Comment: The name of D. H. Lehmer was misspelled (Lehmert). m = 279470273 and div = 4294967291 are suggestions of Park and Miller. div = 2^32-5 a prime number. m also a prime number.   ---- Originally Park and Miller used div = 2,147,483,647 = 2^31-1 a Mersenne Prime and m = 16,807 = 7^5. See http://www.firstpr.com.au/dsp/rand31/p1192-park.pdf