# How to generate random numbers using a seed, and populating a 2D array with them

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need help getting random numbers between one and ten using a seed, and then putting them into a 2D array. The numbers must go out two decimal places. Here is an example of what the output must look like:

```
Please enter the grid size: 3
Please enter the random number seed: 4

7.31 9.19 9.19
6.80 0.78 0.25
6.99 8.05 1.51

Column min values:
6.80 0.78 0.25

Row min values:
7.31
0.25
1.51

Diagonal min value:  0.78
```

Here is the code I have so far. I know it isn't much.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the grid size: ");
    int size = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the random number seed: ");


    double[][] array = new double[size][size];
    System.out.println();
    getArray(array);
    printArray(array);   
}

public static void getArray(double[][] a){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int seed = input.nextInt();
    Random random = new Random(seed);
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
            a[i][j] = random.nextDouble() * 10;
        }
    }
}

    public static void printArray(double[][] a){
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

This is my output:

```
Please enter the grid size: 3
Please enter the random number seed: 1

7.308781907032909 4.100808114922017 2.077148413097171 
3.3271705595951118 9.677559094241207 0.061171822657613006 
9.637047970232077 9.398653887819098 9.471949176631938
```

Getting my numbers to two decimal places is my main problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Generally to find the min in any set of numbers you need to check each value and if the new value is smaller than the smallest one you've seen so far you keep it.  Given the code you already have it shouldn't be too hard to write a function with that check

Comment: While I didn't downvote you're likely to get several more on this question without some improvement.  First you should ask a specific question.  All you've done is list a problem statement and what you have, which makes this look an awful lot like you're asking us to do your assignment for you.  Most people on SO don't want to do your homework for you. A better (specific question) you could ask might be, How do I get my double values to only print to two decimal places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `System.out.printf`

```
for (double[] d : tab) {
    for (double n : d) {
        System.out.printf("%.2f\t", n);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

### Result

```
0,73    0,09    0,49    
0,46    0,45    0,70    
0,28    0,76    0,22
```

---

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you may want to look at the following code for generating arrays of random numbers.

- `Stream.generate` : Generates a stream. Takes a `Supplier` as parameter. Here we gave it `() -> r.doubles(3).toArray()` which basically means : With the random object, generate `3` random doubles and return an array.
- `limit(3)` : Limits the number of `arrays` returned by `Stream.generate` to `3`
- `toArray(double[][]::new)` : As it is a `stream` of `double[]` that we created before, we want to have a new array containing those objects, so what we are doing here is creating an array of `double[]`. So, a `double[][]` and it is the terminal operation of this stream pipe.

---

```
int seed = 5;
Random r = new Random(seed);
double[][] tab = Stream.generate(() -> r.doubles(3).toArray())
                       .limit(3)
                       .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

[**See also**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119583/generating-a-number-of-unique-doubles-in-java/36119613#36119613)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your main problem is getting random numbers that go two decimal places out. Altough this might not be the best or most efficient way to do this, this solution is relatively easy.

You can use:

```
Random ran = new Random(seed);
double number = ran.nextInt(1001) / 100.0D;
```

So you're basically getting a random number between 0 and 1000 (1001 because the upper bound is exclusive) and then dividing it by 100 so you get a double with a decimal fraction that goes two decimal places out.

As for getting minimum values for that you can just iterate over your array and keep track of the lowest number. And after comparing that number to all the other numbers (and updating it if another number is lower) print the number.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. :)